# TypeORM Postgres Migration with sequence instead auto-increment

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I have a column "code" that is not PK and will start from 1000 and increase by 10. I made a sequence `"code_seq"` at a database like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.code_seq
    INCREMENT 10
    START 1000
    MINVALUE 1000
    MAXVALUE 9999999999
    CACHE 1;
```

I want to set as default, like:

```
CREATE TABLE trouble(
id INTEGER, 
code DEFAULT NEXTVAL('public.code_seq'),
```

How to do that using `typeorm` migration?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issues and could not find anywhere how to do this. I ended up figuring out a way that worked for me.

Here is the solution that ended up working for my case.
Try giving this a go and see if that works for you:

```
@Column({
    generated: 'increment', // required to tell typeorm to use sequence/
    default: () => `nextval('code_seq'::regclass)`, // required to tell typeorm we want a function default instead of string.
})
code: number;
```